# Macro not showing up in Macro menu when clicking F5

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I have VBA code that auto forwards all emails to an external account. I can't get the macro to show up in the Macro menu when I click F5 to run it.

```
 Sub AutoForwardAllSentItemsss(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

 Dim strMsg As String
 Dim autoFwd  As Outlook.MailItem
 Set autoFwd = Item.forward
 autoFwd.Recipients.Add "test@test.com"
 autoFwd.Send
 Set autoFwd = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a rule with a run a script option. You will see it when you choose a script.

If that is not what you are asking then.

```
Sub ManuForwardAllSelectedItemsss_V1()

Dim Item As Object
Dim iSend As Long

For iSend = 1 To ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count

    If TypeOf Item Is mailItem Then
        Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection(iSend)
        AutoForwardAllSentItemsss Item
    End If

Next

Set Item = Nothing
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

or

```
Sub ManuForwardAllSelectedItemsss_V2()

Dim manuFwd  As Outlook.mailItem
Dim Item As mailItem

Dim iSend As Long

For iSend = 1 To ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count

    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection(iSend)

    If TypeOf Item Is mailItem Then
        Set manuFwd = Item.Forward
        manuFwd.Recipients.Add "test@test.com"
        manuFwd.Send
    End If
Next

Set Item = Nothing
Set manuFwd = Nothing

End Sub
```